# Views, ViewModels, "WindowViewModels" ...what am I missing here?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, architecture, inversion-of-control

In a presentation logic layer (PLL), I have so-called "view model" classes that implement /extend interfaces defined in the business logic layer (BLL), like this:

```
namespace BLL.Abstract.POCO
{
    // also implemented in data access layer (DAL) by data model entities
    public interface ISomeDomainModelEntity
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        string Description { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace PLL.Abstract.ViewModels
{
    public interface ISomeDomainModelEntityViewModel 
                     : ISomeDomainModelEntity, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }     
}

namespace PLL.Concrete.ViewModels
{
    public class SomeDomainModelEntityViewModel 
                 : ViewModelBase, ISomeDomainModelEntityViewModel
    {
        private string _name;
        private string _description;
        private bool _isSelected;

        public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(() => Name); } }
        public string Description { get { return _description; } set { _description = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(() => Description); } }
        public bool IsSelected { get { return _isSelected; } set { _isSelected = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(() => IsSelected); } }
    }
}
```

Note that `ViewModelBase` is an abstract class which allows for this fancy strongly-typed `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation.

The above implementation's `IsSelected` property is clearly only needed in the presentation layer (visualize a couple dozens of these objects displayed in a list with an `ItemTemplate` which features a `ListBox` that binds its `IsChecked` property to `IsSelected`), and the presentation logic knows how to use it before returning to the business logic layer.

The problem I'm having, is that I find the name "ViewModel" clashes with this:

```
namespace PLL.Abstract.ViewModels // hmmm...
{
    public interface ISomeWindowViewModel
    {
        ObservableCollection<ISomeDomainModelEntityViewModel> SomeItems { get; }
    }
}
```

The implementation of `ISomeWindowViewModel` is ultimately assigned to the view's `DataContext` property:

```
namespace PLL.Concrete.ViewModels
{
    public class SomeWindowViewModel : WindowViewModelBase, ISomeWindowViewModel
    {
        private readonly ObservableCollection<ISomeDomainModelEntityViewModel> _items;

        public SomeWindowViewModel(IView view, ObservableCollection<ISomeDomainModelEntityViewModel> items)
            : base(view)
        {
            _items = items;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ISomeDomainModelEntityViewModel> SomeItems { get { return _items; } set { _items = value; } }
    }
}

namespace PLL.Abstract
{
    public abstract class WindowViewModelBase : ViewModelBase
    {
        public IView View { get; private set; }

        protected WindowViewModelBase(IView view)
        {
            View = view;
            View.DataContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result of a major refactoring I've started after reading about how DI should be applied to WPF in Mark Seeman's *Dependency Injection in .NET* (excellent read so far, not finished yet), and while at first it seemed somewhat backwards to inject the View implementation into the ViewModel's, I can appreciate the gained control/simplicity with handling the displaying and closing of the view. Before the refactoring I had a working application with a BLL that was tightly coupled with DAL and PLL; now the BLL has no dependencies whatsoever and that's awesome.

I'm still in the process of reconfiguring the composition root (using Ninject.Extension.Conventions), so at the end of the day I might realize that I have a couple adjustments to make in order to make it all work... and it could hurt, but I'm ready for it!

So the question(s) is/are as follows:

- I feel like I have way too many interfaces, but I'm totally green with DI configuration using conventions (well, totally green with DI altogether!); configuring the IoC container by convention seems much easier when types implement interfaces... But is this overkill?
- Is the term "ViewModel" overused here? Or rather, is the distinction between "ViewModel" and "WindowViewModel" warranted or I'm missing something? Is it normal that a ViewModel "contains" other ViewModels? If not, is it ok to come up with some "WindowViewModel" name for a ViewModel that's used as a DataContext in a View?
- Is there any blatant architectural flaw visible here that will end up turning the code base into a mess? The idea is to implement MVVM with DI as SOLIDly as possible, but I think I have a LOT to learn still.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463453/why-implement-an-interface-on-viewmodel-and-view-in-mvvm) from last year popped up in the "Similar Questions" list as I was typing this post, and is really starting to blur things even further in my mind - the accepted answer and other comments radically contradict what I've been reading lately. Specifically, that a ViewModel class should be injected with some IView implementation - this question/answer+comments is saying the exact opposite, which is what I had in the first place (a View injected with some IViewModel implementation). Looks like both ways are totally acceptable and it's only a matter of personal preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In my opinion, too many. Architecture should be flexible and you might not keep sticking to one of technique, like IOC, when you smell something. On one hand I did not see the benefit of ISomeDomainModelEntityViewModel, ISomeWindowViewModel and IObservableCollection, there is only one class for each interface, except DI and on the other hand, interface is not essential for DI. I think you might take a look Prism examples to see how they construct ViewModel with DI and when to use interfaces. Usually, if you want to use DI to construct a ViewModel, all dependencies of the ViewModel are services, defined in interface and use IOC to resolve these services. Since these services like have external dependencies so that mocking these interfaces to test is easy. However, most of ViewModel does not have interfaces since they are consumed mainly by View and other ViewModels.
2. I think ViewModel can contain other ViewModel, such as A main ViewModel contains children for each pages.
3. Not obvious. Besides interfaces, personally I do not think it is a good way to put IObservableCollection in IOC.
4. Personally I think injecting IView will break MVVM since ViewModel should not know View. Even an IView, ViewModel have the reference to the View. However in some scenarios if that ViewModel have an IView can make many things much easier, why not? As I said, architecture should be flexible.

Hope it can help.

Comment: Oops, IObservableCollection is a typo - it's really an ObservableCollection, which the view needs for binding.

Comment: About #2: I guess the question rises from #4, since I happen to have VM's that need an IView and others that don't... hence the gut-feeling "need" to make a distinction.